# Trouble writing cookie value to form field

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, google-ads-api

Being a Javascript novice I am having some trouble implementing Google's Adwords GCLID tracking on our site. I am following their code examples show here https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2998031.

You can see the cookie being stored but when trying to retrieve it and populate a hidden form field the result is just blank. I have used other variations but that simply results in "Undefined" as the field value.

Here is the code I'm using

Simplified HTML Form

```
<form class="signup-form" name="signupform" method="post" action="step2.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="gclid" id="gclid" value="" />
</form>
```

Cookie Write Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setCookie(a,d,b){var c=new Date;c.setTime(c.getTime()+864E5*b);b=";
    expires="+c.toGMTString();document.cookie=a+"="+d+b}function getParam(a)     {return(a=RegExp("[?&]"+a+"=([^&]*)").exec(window.location.search))&&decodeURIComponent(a[1].replace(/\+/g," "))}var gclid=getParam("gclid");if(gclid){var gclsrc=getParam("gclsrc");(!gclsrc||-1!==gclsrc.indexOf("aw"))&&setCookie("gclid",gclid,90)};
</script>
```

Cookie Read Script

```
<script> 
  function readCookie(name) { 
      var n = name + "="; 
      var cookie = document.cookie.split(';'); 
      for(var i=0;i < cookie.length;i++) {      
          var c = cookie[i];      
          while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1,c.length);
          }      
          if (c.indexOf(n) == 0){
            return c.substring(n.length,c.length);
          } 
      } 
      return null; 
  } 

  function() {      
      document.getElementById('gclid').value = readCookie('gclid'); 
  } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function() {      
    document.getElementById('gclid').value = readCookie('gclid'); 
}
```

this is a function without a name that's never called. try replacing it with only

```
document.getElementById('gclid').value = readCookie('gclid');
```

I rewrote your write script, I think your cookie is never set.

```
function setCookie(a,d,b) {
    var c = new Date;
    c.setTime(c.getTime()+864E5*b);
    b="; expires=" + c.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = a + "=" + d + b
}

function getParam(a) {
    return(a=RegExp("[?&]"+a+"=([^&]*)").exec(window.location.search))&&decodeURIComponent(a[1].replace(/\+/g," "))
}

var gclid=getParam("gclid");

if(gclid) {
    var gclsrc = getParam("gclsrc");
    if(!gclsrc||-1 !== gclsrc.indexOf("aw")) {
        setCookie("gclid", gclid, 90);
        alert("Cookie Set!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it's a step in the right direction but now it returns a value "Undefined" in that form field value. The test page is updated with this change.

Comment: I added your rewritten write script, please test if your code alerts "Cookie Set!".

Comment: It does alert "Cookie Set" but still returns "Undefined".

Code Inspector Shows:
    <input type="hidden" name="gclid" id="gclid" value="undefined">

There don't appear to be any console errors either.

Comment: Then something with your read function must be wrong, try the framework provided in MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually solved it myself using another example code specifically for Salesforce. Turns out it was a loading issue. The script was executing on load before the form.

Answer (score 0):

Working script modified from https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3285060. I just changed the document.onload to window.onload It seems there was too much going on off screen in the DOM.

```
<script> 
 window.onload = function getGclid() {        
   document.getElementById("gclid").value = (name = new    
 RegExp('(?:^|;\\s*)gclid=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? 
 name.split(",")[1] : ""; } 
</script>
```